# C program error:checking if password is valid

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a c program that checks if the password contains at least :
-1 special character
-1 lowercase letter
-1 uppercase letter
-1 digit 
when i test it, it doesn't work for some reason i've been trying to figure out my error but i didn't know what was wrong

this is my attemp :

```
//check password =at least one upper /at least 1 lower/ at least 1 char;

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

void main() {

    char pass[20]; //password
    int a = 0; //size of the password
    int foundChar = 0;
    int foundUpper = 0;
    int foundLower = 0;
    int foundDigit = 0;
    int i = 0;

    do {
      printf("enter your password : ");
      scanf("%s", pass);
      a = strlen(pass);

      if (a = 8) {

        if (isdigit(pass[i]) && foundDigit == 0) {
          foundDigit = 1;
          i++;
        } else if (isupper(pass[i]) && foundUpper == 0) {
          foundUpper = 1;
          i++;
        } else if (islower(pass[i]) && foundLower == 0) {
          foundLower = 1;
          i++;
        } else if (foundChar == 0) {
          foundChar = 1;
          i++;
        }

      }

    }
    while ((a < 8) || (foundChar == 0) || (foundDigit == 0) || (foundUpper == 0) || (foundUpper = 0));

}
```

Comment: Nice project. Do you have a question?

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  The C++ language has the `std::string` type for handling text, and also `std::transform` for converting stings to all upper or lower case.

Comment: The `scanf` function is evil, see the [FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

Comment: "It doesn't work"? Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at our [intro pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) with special attention to the one on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Tell us what password you give it, and what (wrong) answer it gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not looping through the password.
After your `if (a >= 8)` statement, there is no code to loop around and examine the remaining characters in the string.

Comment: I sorry but I don't quite understand what you meant, can you explain further, the minimum length of the password is supposed to be 8 characters, if the length of the password given is not right there's no point in checking if the other conditions are met .

Comment: Step through your code. When does your program look at `pass[1]` or `pass[2]`?  Use a debugger.